# How to retrieve data from database by scanning QR code?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, qr-code

Hi is it possible to be able to retrieve data from the database after scanning a QR code? Like using the result (eg. 123) to find the product 123 in the database?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrscanner);
    fragment = (BarcodeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sample);
    fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);
    btn = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.scan));
    btn.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I have a code now that will open a new activity and toasting the result after a QR code has been scanned but how do i retrieve data from the database?

```
@Override
public void scanResult(ScanResult result) {
    btn.setEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(QrscannerActivity.this, ProductInfoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, result.getRawResult().getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Where is your database? Do you have one?

Comment: Just use this result `result.getRawResult().getText()` as the value for your WHERE clause.

Comment: yes i have a running database using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Web Database

If your database is stored on a web server, you will need to create a `WebService` on your server so that you can request the data from it. The `WebService` will query the database and return the result to you. You can use this result and display it in your app.

> Local Database

If your database is stored on your device,
You will need to use an SQLite Database for this.
Please take a look at the Android Tutorial on how to use the `SQLiteOpenHelper` Class in order to learn how to do create, insert data and retrieve data from a local database on android.

Tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html